# Identity of derivative of an unknown function

Tags: calculus, linear-transformations

I'm working through a book on tensor notation, and they have a problem where then define a coordinate transformation by:

$$x+iy=f(u+iv)$$
$$z=w$$
Then, it says "Recalling that":
$$f'(u-iv)=x_{,u}+iy_{,u}=y_{,v}-ix_{,v}$$

Why is this expression true?

Comment: See [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations). (perhaps you haven't included the assumption that $f$ is holomorphic?)

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what that means. That terminology is never discussed in the book, so I find it strange that the author would think it common knowledge.

Comment: Here is a picture of the entire problem, for reference: https://i.imgur.com/sYBtDHz.png

Comment: @RafaelHurtado Thanks for providing a picture of the problem. First, note in your question text, it should be "$f'(u+iv)$" instead of "$f'(u-iv)$". Second, the link provided by [John Doe](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/399334/john-doe) explains why that expression is true, in particular in the first few paragraphs at [Complex Differentiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Complex_differentiability).

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to wrap my mind around that.

Comment: @RafaelHurtado "Holomorphic" and "Analytic" are actually basically the same thing, I suppose you're more familiar with this terminology? It just means that the function is complex differentiable.